# How to write a query that return an item name that has the most transaction count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need  to write a query that returns an item name that has the most transaction count. Database structure in pictures. I need to count which  sales. `ItemID` has the biggest count.

Tried to Write a query to my knowledge but I get MySql error

> 1111 invalid use of group functions

This is my query:

```
SELECT item.ItemName 
FROM item 
INNER JOIN sales ON item.id = sales.ItemId   
GROUP BY item.ItemName 
HAVING MAX(COUNT(sales.ItemID) )
```

Expected result is having the item name which has the biggest count of transactions.

[image: This is a picture of the database structure]

Comment: Hi there, you can edit your own post by clicking the "edit" button right under the tags. Or this link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57221805/edit You only want to use the Answer section for answers, not post updates.

Comment: can you try changing select statement into: SELECT item.ItemName, count(*) as NumberOfCounts

Comment: No problem. I went ahead and updated it for you.

Comment: tried  SELECT item.ItemName, count(*) as NumberOfCounts 
FROM item 
INNER JOIN sales ON item.id = sales.ItemId   
GROUP BY item.ItemName 
HAVING MAX(COUNT(NumberOfCounts) ) but the same error

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Order By` and `Limit` instead of having like below:

```
SELECT item.ItemName, count(*)
FROM item 
INNER JOIN sales ON item.id = sales.ItemId   
GROUP BY item.ItemName
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Works like charm.Just needed to change ASC to DESC

Comment: @SimasKasparaitis Ah sorry, fixed it, thanks for warning. Should've drunk more coffee before answering a question :)